# whats the difference in batch_size in fit() and image_dataset_from_directory()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I was trying to change batch size while training so I run the fit method in a loop and change the batch size, but we already define batch size in `image_dataset_from_directory()`, What if I put different batch sizes in these two functions, and is there a way that I get to control the batch size in fit method and not be affected by `image_dataset_from_directory()`
Heres my code

```
  train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

  model.fit(
      
            train_ds,
            validation_data=val_ds,
            epochs=epoch,
            batch_size=batch_size,
            steps_per_epoch=10,
            callbacks=call

            )
```

the code has been taken from this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification) of tensorflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`image_dataset_from_directory` is a generator and so specifying `batch_size` in `model.fit()` will do nothing. See the docs on [`model.fit()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit):

> **batch_size** Integer or None. Number of samples per gradient update. If unspecified, batch_size will default to 32. Do not specify the batch_size if your data is in the form of datasets, generators, or keras.utils.Sequence instances (since they generate batches).

As you can see in the example you referred, the Tensorflow tutorial doesn't specify `batch_size` in `model.fit()`:

```
epochs=10
history = model.fit(
  train_ds,
  validation_data=val_ds,
  epochs=epochs
)
```

The batch size will be what you specified in the generator, and the argument will be ignored in `model.fit()`